# Are a plane and a circle homeomorphic?

Tags: algebraic-topology

The circle, denoted as $\mathcal{S}^1$, has the form $x^2+y^2=1$. The projective line in a plane ($\mathcal{P}^1 \in \mathcal{A}^2$) and circle are homeomorphic. And I think projective lines can span the whole plane. So plane and circle are homeomorphic, which is my guess. So I wonder whether a plane and a circle are homeomorphic.

Comment: You seem to be confusing plane with projective plane, please be clear and consistent. Which do you mean?

Comment: I mean just plane, not projective plane, in the question of "Are a plane and a circle homeomorphic". I am learning topology myself and confusing about some notions.

Comment: Unfortunately the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the unit circle $S^1$ are not homeomorphic. Indeed, suppose by contradiction that there is an homeomorphism $f: S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, then since compactness is a topological property and The unit circle is compact, would lead us to say that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is compact, that is the desired contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

No a plane and circle are not homeomorphic. A circle is a 1 manifold (locally an interval) and a plane is trivially a 2 manifold. So by a dimension argument alone they are not homeomorphic.

A circle is not even homeomorphic to a 1 dimensional plane, i.e. a line. The circle is compact, while the line is not. Thus, it is not possible to exhibit a continuous map from the circle onto a line.

Comment: you answered the question in the title only, which seems not to be the actual question, if you read it

Comment: @Mirko as you noted, it is unclear which is OP's question. I interpreted it to be the question in the title. In addition, the body of the question doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: then that deserves a comment, not an answer

Comment: @Mirko why? I answered adequately (in my opinion) the question in the title. If OP does not find it helpful, he or she can feel free to not accept and wait for another answer to come along. Also please don't confuse your opinion for everyone's accepted decorum

Comment: sorry, I do not understand the meaning of "decorum", could you please use plain English? Of course what I express my own opinion, any interpretation to the opposite it completely unfounded

Answer (score 2):

You can consider fundamental group, for circle $\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$ but for the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^2)=0$.

Intuitively, one can shrink a loop to a point on the plane, but not on the circle.

Comment: you answered the question in the title only, which seems not to be the actual question, if you read it

Comment: Unfortunately the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the unit circle $S^1$ are not homeomorphic. Indeed, suppose by contradiction that there is an homeomorphism $f: S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, then since compactness is a topological property and The unit circle is compact, would lead us to say that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is compact, that is the desired contradiction.